10th Anniversary of Emacs SE!
This week Emacs SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

I hope the platform allows me to accept multiple answers to a single question.

I usually find this site when I search for a solution to an Emacs problem or question with Duckduckgo. There are usually others who have asked the same question and excellent answers from people with loads of knowledge. Thank you for ten years of making it easy for people to share their experience and knowledge with others and thank you to the community for sharing!

This is one of the nicest Stack Exchange communities out there!
Everyone is really helpful and I've found a lot of cool Emacs utilities thanks to this forum.
Congratulations for the 10 year anniversary and for many more!!
